# Differences between Win32 FASM .inc files

Tags: windows, assembly, fasm

What is the difference between the win32a, win32ax, win32axp, win32w, win32wx, and win32wxp .inc files in Flat Assembler? I tried to find it in the FASM documentation but I couldn't...

Thanks in advance,
The ChristonianCoder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There are six headers for 32-bit Windows that you can choose from,
>   with names starting with win32 followed by either a letter a for using
>   the ASCII encoding, or a letter w for the WideChar encoding. The
>   win32a.inc and win32w.inc are the basic headers, the win32ax.inc and
>   win32wx.inc are the extended headers, they provide more advanced
>   macroinstructions, those extensions will be discussed separately.
>   Finally the win32axp.inc and win32wxp.inc are the same extended
>   headers with enabled feature of checking the count of parameters in
>   procedure calls.

http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=win32